# Implementing overlays for ECL Thumbnails

Tags: 2013, ecl

I have implemented an ECL provider which generates thumbnails of my images. I would now like to show some form of overlay to indicate whether the item is checked out (in the external system), published, and eventually add a restricted watermark.

Are there any examples of overlaying the standard checked-out or published icons on ECL items,  or samples of how to use the `GetThumbnailImage()` method with the `IList<IThumbnailOverlay> thumbnailOverlays` overload that I see in the ECL API docs? Would this be an appropriate way to implement such functionality, or should I just manipulate the byte array which is returned by the  GetThumbnailImage() method of my class implementing  `IContentLibraryContext`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the overlay icon like this:

```
int actualSize;
byte[] iconData = Library.HostServices.GetIcon(
                      Library.IconBasePath,
                      null,
                      "your-icon-name",
                      16,
                      out actualSize);
```

As CreateThumbnailOverlay requires a stream, you need to create a memory stream. So the code will look something like this:

```
using (MemoryStream iconStream = new MemoryStream(iconData, false))
{
    // This implies item is a MultiMediaItem already loaded and GetContent
    // returns an actual image, if not you need to get the main thumbnail
    // image by other means
    IContentResult content = item.GetContent(null);
    try
    {
        IList<IThumbnailOverlay> overlays = new List<IThumbnailOverlay>
        {
            // maxWidth and maxHeight specifies the requested thumbnail size,
            // so this icon is placed in the lower left corner.
            Library.HostServices.CreateThumbnailOverlay(
                 0,
                 maxHeight - actualSize,
                 actualSize,
                 actualSize,
                 iconStream)
        };

        return Library.HostServices.CreateThumbnailImage(
            maxWidth,
            maxHeight,
            content.Stream,
            maxWidth,
            maxHeight,
            overlays);
    }
    finally
    {
        content.Stream.Close();
    }
}
```

Tridion thumbnails do not display overlays for checked out etc. This is the reason ECL doesn't add the overlays automatically.

You can of course manipulate the bytes directly - but as ECL runs in a Windows service  you can't use the classes within System.Drawing. You can use the WPF classes, but these require an STA thread.

There might be a third party library you can use to manipulate images on a MTA thread, but unless you require something more than just overlaying images I would recommend sticking to the methods provided by ECL.

Comment: Thanks Lars, this code explains a lot, but I am still not sure where I should be putting this? I am also not clear how this can get the existing Published and CheckedOut overlays. Are there some specific "your-icon-name" values for this?

Comment: This is pretty much a complete implementation of IContentLibraryContext.GetThumbnailImage - the only part that is missing is where it initialize the item variable - Which could simply be a call to GetItem. There are no easy way to get hold of the checked out etc icons - Either include them with your provider, or try to locate them on the server. But again: Tridion normally does not display these overlays on thumbnails - so do you really need them or do you just think you need them (like I did)? :)

Comment: Sorry, I missed the part where you mention it's checked out on the remote system you want to display. I would consider not using standard Tridion icons for this, after all the item can also be checked out in Tridion.